# Files and attachments non editable

Tags: lightning-experience, opportunity, files

recently I noticed some files attached to opportunities are non editable, and I mean some, because these files should be downloaded and then uploaded once again, after doing this is it has enabled all the options.

I have to add the fact that both files has the same extension, but one shows a chain, I already tried using the Modify all data permission, login as the file owner and nothing worked.

[image: First file with no edit options, second file with edit options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously In the Salesforce classic, Salesforce stored all of the files for a parent record as an [attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) object.

With Salesforce's new user Interface Lightning, All the files are stored under [Content Version Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm). With Content objects, you get better versioning, distribution, and security controls.

`Notes and Attachments` related list you have seems to have records from the Attachment object. When you are uploading the new files it is properly loaded as Files (Content Version) and hence you see all of those actions.

Salesforce recommends you stay away from using Notes and Attachment related list in your app and instead use Files related list for files and Notes related list.

You can read about this [here](http://The%20%27Notes%20&%20Attachments%27%20related%20list%20will%20eventually%20be%20phased%20out%20in%20favor%20of%20the%20individual%20%27Files%27%20and%20%27Notes%27%20related%20lists.)

From the docs

> The 'Notes & Attachments' related list will eventually be phased out in favor of the individual 'Files' and 'Notes' related lists.

Also, Salesforce recommends you migrate all attachments to Salesforce Files and Notes to new Enhanced notes using help [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315846&type=1&mode=1).